# How to format large Size HDD quickly

Tags: linux, mkfs

In windows we can do a Quick format just by right clicking the device and boom format.

In linux How to do the same I mean if the size of HDD is 2TB or more it takes along time to format using

mkfs.ext3 /dev/sda*

Is there an option to format it quickily

Comment: Are you forced to stick to ext3 or is ext4 an option, too?

Comment: Yes Hauke Im using ext3 now

Comment: That wasn't the question.

Comment: this is the quick version, the long version requires '-c'

Answer (score 1):

You can check that you are using the following option according to the man page you should be unless you explicitly turn it off.

man mkfs.ext3

```
lazy_itable_init[= <0 to disable, 1 to enable>]
```

If enabled and the uninit_bg feature is enabled, the inode table will not be fully initialized by mke2fs. This speeds up filesystem initialization noticeably, but it requires the kernel to finish initializing the filesystem in the background when the filesystem is first mounted. If the option value is omitted, it defaults to 1 to enable lazy inode table initialization."

Never used this myself as although formatting ext3 is not instant it's nothing compared to a non quick format of ntfs.

Comment: Are you sure this is available for ext3? Seems to me that it is an ext4 feature.

Comment: Why not use ext4?